# How can I find the UIFont pointSize necessary to get a desired lineHeight or other metric?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uifont

You can ask a `UIFont` instance for its `lineHeight` metric:

```
UIFont *const font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 10];
CGFloat lineHeight = [font lineHeight];
```

If I want a particular lineHeight, (20, say), how can I create a UIFont with that size?

Comment: Why don't you use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property of UILabel?

Comment: @sha that only lets you adjust the width of a specific piece of text to fit a given width in a UILabel. It doesn't work if you need a specific lineHeight, or other font metric. It doesn't work if you're not using UILabel – in my case I am rendering on to a CGContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

My limited analysis suggests, surprisingly to me, that linear interpolation can be used. Here's a category on `UIFont` that will do what's needed:

```
@interface UIFont (FontWithLineHeight)
+(UIFont*) systemFontWithLineHeight: (CGFloat) lineHeight;
@end
```

With an implementation:

```
@implementation UIFont (FontWithLineHeight)
+(UIFont*) systemFontWithLineHeight:(CGFloat)lineHeight
{
  const CGFloat lineHeightForSize1 = [[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 1] lineHeight];
  const CGFloat pointSize = lineHeight / lineHeightForSize1;
  return [UIFont systemFontOfSize: pointSize];
}
@end
```

Used like this:

```
UIFont *const font = [UIFont systemFontWithLineHeight: 20];
NSLog(@"%f", [font lineHeight]);
```

Which outputs:

```
2014-01-08 16:04:19.614 SpikeCollectionView[6309:60b] 20.000000
```

Which is what was asked for.

### Analysis

It seems that the `lineHeight` of a `UIFont` scales linearly with the `pointSize`. In other words, if you make the `pointSize` twice as much, then the `lineHeight` will be twice as much too. If you halve the `pointSize` you also halve the `lineHeight`. This means that interpolation can be used to find the `pointSize` that will provide a given `lineHeight` or other metric.

Here's code that shows the linearity:

```
const CGFloat lineHeight1 = [[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 1] lineHeight];
const CGFloat lineHeight10 = [[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 10] lineHeight];
const CGFloat lineHeight100 = [[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 100] lineHeight];
const CGFloat ratio1_10 = lineHeight10 / lineHeight1;
const CGFloat ratio10_100 = lineHeight100 / lineHeight10;
NSLog(@"%f", ratio1_10);
NSLog(@"%f", ratio10_100);
```

The output is:

```
2014-01-08 15:56:39.326 SpikeCollectionView[6273:60b] 9.999999
2014-01-08 15:56:39.329 SpikeCollectionView[6273:60b] 10.000001
```

### Caution

I've only tested this for the system font on iOS 7. Other fonts may not exhibit linear scaling of their metrics under scalings to their pointSize. If someone could confirm whether this is guaranteed or when it won't work, that would be marvellous. If you try this for other `UIFont` and it doesn't work, please comment or extend this answer, or add another.

If linear scaling of the metrics is not guaranteed, it would be necessary to search for the required `pointSize`. You will need a "root finding" numeric algorithm. The [Illinois Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method#Illinois_algorithm) would work for this.

Comment: Just what I was looking for ;)

Comment: @NicolasManzini I'm glad it's useful to someone else! It is worth noting that other properties (such as the width of a string) seem to be piecewise linear but with discontinuities. So, they're locally linear, and a linear solution will work fairly well, but if you do want a really robust solution, you need to use a search such as the secant method I suggested.

Comment: Actually – don't look at Secant, look at [False Position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method) method, which is really terribly simple, very robust, and extremely quick. I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: In fact! Don't look at False Position Method, look at the Illinois Method, which is a much better variant (see the same wikipedia link, though), or the bisection method. I wish I knew this stuff :-) And I also wish it was a normal thing for programmers to have a root finder in their tool box.